# Using Backbone.js View as Require.js Dependency

Tags: javascript, jquery, backbone.js, underscore.js, require

How can I include a view from another file (e.g. Views.js) in a JavaScript file loaded as a Require.js module? I receive a "Uncaught TypeError: object is not a function" error when I try to instantiate myView.

```
define([
  'jQuery',
  'Underscore',
  'Backbone',
  'src/Views'
], function ($, _, Backbone, myView) {

  new myView ({ });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Do your "src/views.js" have a return value?

some like this:

```
define(['underscore', 'backbone'], function(_, Backbone) {
    var view = Backbone.View.extend({

        ......

    });
    return view; //the return value is essential
});
```